# jQuery onclick show first parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, parent-child

I have an issue with a show of a parent div at onclick.
As here:

```
 $('#click').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().closest('div').slideToggle("fast");

});

http://jsfiddle.net/bk1hLoyb/
```

I need to show the .show div at the li click, and i need to hide the first when i click another.
Someone know's a method?
Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id's should be unique on the page.

```
$('.click').click(function() {
        $('.show').hide();
        $(this).find('.show').slideToggle("fast");
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bk1hLoyb/11/

Comment: Thanks so much! Works

Answer (score 0):

First Id's must be unique so change it for:

```
<li class="click">
        <a href="#">Bye</a>
        <div class="show">Hey</div>
</li>
```

and the code change it for:

```
$('.click').click(function() {
        $(this).find('div').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j8jhag87/)

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

- remove all duplicate IDs
- if you must use a selector on the `li` elements, use a class
- `.show` is a child of the `li` that's clicked, so there's no need to use `.parent()` or `.closest()`.

Code:

```
$('.click').click(function() {
    $('.show', this).slideToggle("fast");    
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bk1hLoyb/12/)

**BONUS**

- [`$(elm).find('.selector')` is equivalent to `$('.selector', elm)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/)
- [Also written as `jQuery( selector [, context ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/)
- [When `context` is not specified, it is assumed to be `document`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/)
- [Thus **$(elm)** is equivalent to **$(elm, document)**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

On your "li"s change the id to a class so you can reference multiple divs.

Then on the script looks like this:

```
$('.click a').click(function() {
    var item = $(this);
    $(this).parent().siblings().find('.show').slideUp(400,function(){
        item.parent().find('.show').slideDown(400);
     });
});
```

See it working on your fiddle (sorry for updating without forking)